# Pillow is installed but still getting an error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-3.5

I have pillow installed and I have followed multiple answers however, when i try to run my program it says *"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'*

I have already downloaded pillow through GIT Bash by following instructions from answers on how to and I have already tried replacing the 'pillow' for 'PIL' but i get the same error.

My code:

```
from Pillow import ImageTk,Image
```

EDIT: I am using version 3.6.5 of Python

Comment: In cases like this it often is the case that people have two versions of Python installed, and the module is installed in the wrong one. What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows  / windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment on your post.

First, try these import statements:

```
import PIL
# OR
from PIL import *
```

I just want to ask you to make sure that PIL is correctly installed. Run the following python code as a single-line python file. This will print out a list of python modules installed.

```
help('modules')
```

See if PIL or Pillow on the list. If not, then PIL is not correctly installed.

I was also just wondering if you can use `pip` (python's package manager) to re-install Pillow. Since you're using python 3.6.5, `pip` is pre-installed. If you don't mind using `pip`, execute the following command in CMD on Windows or Terminal on a Mac to install PIL with pip:

```
python -m pip install pillow
```

Try again with your original import statements with `PIL` and `Pillow`. If none of these works, try the following import statements, again:

```
import PIL
# OR
from PIL import *
```

How this helps.

Comment: pillow is not on the list of plugins and it may be what Roland Smith said cause i definately installed it

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions. Are you by any chance using Anaconda or venv? Are you running your program in an IDE/Editor

Comment: running my program in Python Shell and using IDLE to edit

Comment: Can you check if your Python PATH is correctly configured?

Comment: i have a path going to c:\Python36\, is that right?

Comment: Could you try running your python file using CMD instead of Python Shell?

Comment: Ok, let's try this: instead of running using python filename.py, do python3.6 or python 3.6.5 then filename.py. Also please try all the possible import statements.

Comment: You could also do `pip3` to install PIL.

Comment: I am unable to install PIL as it isnt available for Python  3.6.5

Comment: @Omen Have you tried doing `pip3 install Pillow` instead of `pip3 install PIL`?